# AVFoundation : How to get the audio sample buffer data of 1 second completely , 44100 float values

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation

AVFoundation : How to get the audio sample buffer data, 44100 float , 1 second after 1 second

get sample data directly

```
var arrayAudioSampleCount = 1
var arrayAudioSampleCluster = [Float]()

func sample(){

        let bus = 0
        let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
        let inputFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: bus)
        inputNode.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 1024, format: inputFormat){ (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in

            for i in 0 ..< Int(buffer.frameLength){
                var sample = (convertedBuffer.floatChannelData?.pointee[i])!
                if( sample > 1 ){
                    sample = 1
                }
                if( sample < -1 ){
                    sample = -1
                }
                let theSample = sample * Float(Int16.max)
                arrayAudioSampleCluster.append(theSample)

            }


        }
        audioEngine.prepare()
    }
```

Code to handle data with Timer

```
func startTimer(){

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(PlayerViewController.update(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire()

        RunLoop.main.add( timer , forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)

}


@objc func update(_ timer: Timer){
    print("Total sample: \(arrayAudioSampleCount) s")

    print(arrayAudioSampleCluster.count)
    arrayAudioSampleCount += 1
}
```

> Total sample: 1 s
>
> 48000
>
> Total sample: 2 s
>
> 96000
>
> Total sample: 3 s
>
> 144000

Device is Ipad Air 3

The data of 1 second, is more than 44100, the sample rate needed.

And I get the full data

---

get sample data converted, downsample to 44100

code of fetch data:

```
func sample(){

        let bus = 0
        let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
        let inputFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: bus)


        let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 1, interleaved: true)!

        let converter = AVAudioConverter(from: inputFormat, to: outputFormat)!


        inputNode.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 1024, format: inputFormat){ (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in

            var newBufferAvailable = true

            let inputCallback: AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { inNumPackets, outStatus in
                if newBufferAvailable {
                    outStatus.pointee = .haveData
                    newBufferAvailable = false

                    return buffer
                } else {
                    outStatus.pointee = .noDataNow
                    return nil
                }
            }

            let convertedBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: outputFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(outputFormat.sampleRate) * buffer.frameLength / AVAudioFrameCount(buffer.format.sampleRate))!

            var error: NSError?
            let status = converter.convert(to: convertedBuffer, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputCallback)

            for i in 0 ..< Int(convertedBuffer.frameLength){
                var sample = (convertedBuffer.floatChannelData?.pointee[i])!
                if( sample > 1 ){
                    sample = 1
                }
                if( sample < -1 ){
                    sample = -1
                }
                let theSample = sample * Float(Int16.max)
                arrayAudioSampleCluster.append(theSample)

            }


        }
        audioEngine.prepare()
    }
```

> ```
> Total sample: 1 s
> 44085
> Total sample: 2 s
> 88185
> Total sample: 3 s
> 132285
> ```

Device is Ipad Air 3

***I lost the 15 float values in the first second,  How to get it right?***